# Use Pandoc to convert Latex equations to RST for Sphinx

Tags: latex, pandoc, markup, restructuredtext

I am trying to convert Latex scripts to restructured text (rST) via [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/).
This works well, except for labelled equations.
Is there some configuration/filter for Pandoc which can correctly format equation labels?

[For example](https://pandoc.org/try/?text=%5Csection%7BTest%20section%7D%0A%0ASome%20test%20equation%20%0A%0A%5Cbegin%7Bequation%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Clabel%7Btest_eqn%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20a%20%3D%20100%0A%5Cend%7Bequation%7D%0A%0A%0AAnd%20then%20we%20reference%20%5Cref%7Btest_eqn%7D.&from=latex&to=rst&standalone=0), the source Latex

```
\section{Test section}

Some test equation 

\begin{equation}
    \label{test_eqn}

    a = 100
\end{equation}


And then we reference \ref{test_eqn}.
```

yields

```
Test section
============

Some test equation

.. math::

   \label{test_eqn}

       a = 100

And then we reference `[test_eqn]`_.

.. _[test_eqn]: #test_eqn
```

but the desired output is

```
Test section
============

Some test equation

.. math::
    :label: test_eqn

    a = 100

And then we reference :eq:`test_eqn`.
```